# Send updated data to lwc lightning-modal component

Tags: lightning-web-components, modal

I am using the lightning-modal component which is opened via JS in the parent component. I pass in a progress value to the modal using the @api decorator on the modal component. I can pass the value in when the modal opens but as that progress value increases on the parent component, the updated value does not get passed down to the modal. It looks like you can trigger events from the modal to the parent but is there a way to send updated info to an already opened modal?

Here is the code from the parent JS controller:

```
// Open the modal showing the user their percentage
        const importwindow = await ImportProgressModal.open({
            size: 'small',
            progress: this.progressPercentage,
            description: 'Modal that allows a user to see the progress of their import job',
        });
```

EDIT 1:
I import the modal definition at the top of the parent JS controller.

```
import ImportProgressModal from 'c/modalImportWizardProgress';
```

The modal component extends LightningModal. Here is the modal controller code where I was hoping to pass in the dynamic/updating progress property (progress):

```
import LightningModal from 'lightning/modal'
export default class ModalImportWizardProgress extends LightningModal {
@api progress;
}
```

Comment: What is ImportProgressModal? It's the implementation there that's either going to be able to accept new data, or not.

Comment: @sfdcfox just added a new edit. Please let me know if you need more details. Thank you!

Comment: Still not enough detail. At minimum, the open method would be useful, plus however the ImportProgressModal class knows which component it is, etc. I'd rather see too much detail than too little.

Comment: I don't think you can do that. Since every modal is a new instance. How would you even know which of the opened modal you need to pass the data to.